# File gets locked after setting attributes

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method which saves the object into the file. The object gets modified and saved multiple times. The problem is that when I'm trying to save object for the second time into the same file, I'm getting the UnautorizedAccessException. Here is the code:

```
public void Save(string path)
{
            string fileName = String.Format("{0}\\{1}", path, DataFileName);
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
            {
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                formatter.Serialize(fs, this);
                File.SetAttributes(fileName, FileAttributes.Hidden);
            }
}
```

What's the most interesting, is that if I comment the line

```
File.SetAttributes(fileName, FileAttributes.Hidden);
```

problem disappears. How comes? And how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you close the stream on the first save?

Comment: Shouldn't your `SetAttributes()` call be outside the `using` anyway?

Comment: Unhide, save, rehide.

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn Are you suggesting that you can't write to a hidden file?

Comment: @Anon, I may be wrong, but i thought "using" works for that

Comment: You are correct, I thought you were calling a different save method the first time.

Comment: @itsme86 What's the difference if it's inside or outside?

Comment: Would it be possible to re work your logic. Say write to string builder, then after that is finished, save to the file one time.

Comment: @Anon, not really, as it's svn-like program, which synchronizes local directory with one at Amazon S3, and that object contains files metadata, which changes all the time.

Comment: @KorsaR Inside the using, you still have the file open, but outside (after) it has been disposed. Since you're using a static method to set the attributes, you don't need the file to be open.

Answer (score 4):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode.aspx) says this about `FileMode.Create`:

> Specifies that the operating system should create a new file. If the
>   file already exists, it will be overwritten. This requires
>   FileIOPermissionAccess.Write permission. FileMode.Create is equivalent
>   to requesting that if the file does not exist, use CreateNew;
>   otherwise, use Truncate. **If the file already exists but is a hidden
>   file, an UnauthorizedAccessException exception is thrown.**

Which is exactly what you are seeing. So the solution seems to be either use a different mode, or as suggested in the comments, unhide -> save -> hide.